# How can I access first index of gameData

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the data I'm getting from API

```
gameData: Array(3)
0: {ROW_COUNT: 6, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: Array(6)}
1: {ROW_COUNT: 6, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: Array(6)}
2: {ROW_COUNT: 6, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: Array(6)}
length: 3

index 0 having this -

COLUMN_COUNT: 7
ROW_COUNT: 6
board: Array(6)
0: (7) [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (7) [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (7) [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (7) [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
4: (7) [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]
5: (7) [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
state: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

how can I send/access only the data of 0 index
and after then how can I access board? do I have to destructure it if yes then how?

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abNth.png)

`In this code I want to define rows = api's row , cols = api's cols and board = api's board. in the json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this by **destruction first index of Array Data**.

**For Example :**

```js
// Assuming you have the gameData array from the API response as below
const gameData = [
  { ROW_COUNT: 6, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 12, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 12, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 4, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
];

// you can destructure the first index of gameData to get rows, cols, and board like this
const [{ ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT,state, board }] = gameData;

console.log({ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT,state,board})
```

**EDITED :**

How to access dynamically :

```js
// Assuming you want to access the data at index 0 in gameData array
const gameData = [
  { ROW_COUNT: 6, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 12, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 12, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
  { ROW_COUNT: 4000, COLUMN_COUNT: 7, state: 0, board: [ [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ] },
];

// Accessing data at index  dynamically
const index = 3;
const { ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT, state, board } = gameData[index];

console.log({ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT,state,board})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works. Can you please tell me how can I access the 2nd index? it is giving me an error if I do this-> const [{ ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT,state, board }] = gameData[1];

Comment: Hi @SagarSingh , I have updated the code you can access any index by changeing index value in above mentioned code. Hope this help you !!

Comment: If that Index doesn't exist then it will throuw error

Comment: when I try to access by specifying a particular index it throughs me an error "TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."

Comment: If you have that error  : {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ROW_COUNT' of 'gameData[index]' as it is undefined.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 22,
  "colno": 9
} It means you are accessing that object index which is not present in array. Please check gameData.length @SagarSingh